# What was the erratically jumping star like object

Tags: star, amateur-observing

Oct 31st'21 around 11.15 pm. we saw a bright star like object, jumping erratically in all directions, constantly twinkling,occasionally looking coloured. All other stars were still. We were Looking towards east coast from north east Gippsland Vic. Easily seen by naked eye. When looking through binoculars it looked like a cluster of stars, the configuration constantly changed shape.It was still jumping around at 12.09am when we stopped looking

Comment: This sounds like a Starlink cluster.  Those are low Earth Orbit satellites which are launched in swarms and seem to sparkle as they individually catch the light.  They are launched in dozens and are very impressive, even if you know what you are looking at.  Eventually the satellites disperse into their own orbits and the cluster effect is gone.

Comment: @john Not really.  It sounds like a "u.f.o." and we really can't answer questions about "flying" objects.  At any rate, it doesn't match the description of any astronomical body.

Comment: It seems a drone, from your description

Comment: Would you see a starlink cluster 11 pm? what light is it reflecting from? took a video with an ipad, not that good but will try to get it on this site, is anyone wanted interested in looking at it?

Comment: @James K.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JELgfanNIPg  I was under the impression that these are satellite group releases.  This sort of thing is being seen regularly and I don't think UFO covers it.  Cube Sats, Swarm Technologies (the company), Starlink; one of these.  There was a TV program, possibly on Accuweather, discussing these.  I've seen them following known launches.  Or we maybe should get Sigourney Weaver to suit up again.

Comment: @Diane Bailey; Obviously, I can't say for certain what you saw, but I've seen similar between 9:30-11:00 following known launches.  Maybe not Starlink per se, but multiply launched satellite systems.  Youtube has video from Las Vegas which seems to get a fair number of reports.  Note I did not suggest as an answer, just a comment.  Others seem to disagree.  I know you can find satellite positions online. Might check time, date and location.

Comment: No satellite or satelite swarm can be described as "jumping erratically", or forming a configuation that "constantly changes shape". Nor could any naked eye satellite be visibile for nearly an hour.